# Can Hibernate be made to work with immutable records for mutable entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, immutability

I am trying to implement an immutable data store on a PostgreSQL db, the point would be to never update records but rather insert a new row every time an entity gets updated, as described in [this article](http://nyeggen.com/post/2014-02-01-immutable-sql/)

Is it possible to make Hibernate work with such a database configuration?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that does the underlying work instead of Hibernate.